# Is there a way to catch return statements from contextmanager in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to catch an SQLAlchemy operation result but am unsure if I can do it. Following is the code -

```py
@contextmanager
def transaction_scope(session, close_at_exit=False):
    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
        return True
    except Exception:
        session.rollback()
        return False
    finally:
        if close_at_exit:
            session.close()

with Session() as session:
    with transaction_scope(session):
        session.add(row)
        # Catch if the above insert (add) operation is successful or not
```

I am inserting a record into the database. I want to get the boolean response from the `transaction_scope()` if my insert operation is successful or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can always catch, respond to, and rethrow an exception.

```
with Session() as session:
    with transaction_scope(session):
        try:
            session.add(row)
        except Exception as exc:
            # Oh no! It failed! Do something here...
            raise
```

Note that the `raise` keyword, without an exception, can only be used in an `except` block and re-raises the current exception with its original stack trace intact. So we can respond to the exception and then re-raise it to allow the `transaction_scope` to roll back the transaction as it's supposed to.

Comment: I already tried this. `try: session.add(row); return {'success': True}; except: return {'success': False}` but it does not return `False` in case of an exception. I believe the reason is that an error encountered in `session.add(row)` will be caught in `@contextmanager` and that is why I need to catch the return True/False from it.